# Scheduling a Cloud DataStore Export in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

I have followed this tutorial step by step https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/schedule-export but I have a problem when I want to assign the Storage Admin role on my bucket with the gsutil command-line tool

```
gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:YOUR_PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:storage.admin \
gs://BUCKET_NAME
```

I have this error:

> BadRequestException: 400 Role roles/storage.storage.admin is not supported for this resource.

However, I can exporting and importing Entities with this commands

```
gcloud datastore export --namespaces="(default)" gs://${BUCKET}

gcloud datastore import gs://${BUCKET}/[PATH]/[FILE].overall_export_metadata
```

Comment: Notice a repeated `storage` string in your error message: `roles/storage.storage.admin`. Try the cmd without `storage.` in it: `gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:YOUR_PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:admin \
gs://BUCKET_NAME`. Maybe the `storage.` prefix is inserted automatically? (in which case the doc is not up2date). Just speculating ;)

Comment: The answer above is correct. @DanCornilescu could you please add it as an answer then Freddy, could you mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 5):

Converting a comment to an answer...

The error message contains a duplicate `storage` item: `roles/storage.storage.admin`.

Invoking the following command instead (without the `.storage` string) appears to be working:

```
gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:YOUR_PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:admin gs://BUCKET_NAME
```